# removing duplication in google search api?

Tags: python, google-search-api

I am performing a google search in my application through google search api. It gives me the duplicate results. How to avoid it. I refer http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the filtering option used at :

- http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/64/xml_reference.html

It uses two types of filter:

- Duplicate Snippet Filter
- Duplicate Directory Filter

So when calling, mark Filter=True

```
results = server.doGoogleSearch(key, 'mark', 0, 10, False, "", ...)
```

The API provides the following argument:

```
key - Your Google API key
q - The search word
start - The index of the result to start on
maxResults - The number of results to return.
filter - If True, Google will filter out duplicate pages
restrict - Set this to country plus a country code to get results only from a particular country
safeSearch - If True, Google will filter out porn sites
lr (“language restrict”) - Set this to a language code
ie and oe must be "utf-8"
```

Comment: Google API accepts Filter=True / False option and I assume that the duplicate filter is enabled for public google too.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock : The Ajax search API documentation , google Appliance  API both provides filter as options for search API